# Class instances inside a loop in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create class objects through loop, but I am not able to find solution

```
class burger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ketchup='yes'
        self.mayo= 'No'

for i in range(5):
    burger_i= burger()
```

And in return I want these objects created (I don't want a list):

```
burger_1
burger_2 ...
```

Comment: Use list or dictionary to hold multiple object.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
class burger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ketchup='yes'
        self.mayo= 'No'

for i in range(5):
    globals()["burger_%d" % i] = burger()
```

But really, you should **just use a list**!

Comment: Modifying `locals()` is specifically warned against in the docs, and needn't have any effect.  It only works in this instance because `locals() is globals()`.

Comment: Yea, as I said, it _should work_, but it's bad. Changing locals or globals is an answer to the exact question the OP asked - the sensible thing to do is _use a list_.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that you usually *can't* change `locals()` (modulo one implementation-dependent exception) and modify variables that way.  Try it in a function, for example.  `globals()`, on the other hand, you *can* modify, ugly as it is.

Comment: You're right, I never before really tried to modify locals. So I've changed it to globals in the answer (which doesn't make it better), and put more emphasis on the suggestion to use a list :)

Answer (score 0):

Naming variables dynamically like that is simply a bad idea. You *should* use a list (or a dict if you want more flexible naming). Something like this:

```
burgers = [burger() for i in range(5)]
```

Now your `burger_i` is simply `burgers[i]`.